# "Инструкция по..." или "Инструкция, как..." - допустимы оба варианта?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Например, "инструкция, как стричь собак" или "инструкция по стрижке собак". 
Является ли несогласованным сочетание "инструкция, как..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ИНСТРУКЦИЯ**, -и; ж. [лат. instructio - наставление] 1. **Свод правил**, устанавливающий порядок и способ осуществления чего-л. **И. по технике безопасности.** Составить инструкцию. 2. **Руководящие указания**, наставления. Дать подробные инструкции.

Возможны такие варианты

1) **Название**

Инструкция (какая?) по стрижке собак(= свод правил).

2) **Несогласованное определение в простом предложении**:

К новому материалу прилагалась инструкция (какая?) по стрижке собак (= свод правил).

3) **Придаточное предложение (изъяснительное)**:

В книге дана инструкция (о том), как надо стричь собак (= указания).

**Примеры**

В книге дана **инструкция, как** это можно сделать.

Подробная **инструкция о том, как** управлять этой штукой, умещается на жестяной табличке размером в две пачки сигарет

Comment: Спасибо. А "описание, как стричь собак" - так можно построить фразу?

Comment: Думаю, что только в предложении, например: Здесь дано описание, как стричь собак. В качестве названия такая фраза не подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

"Инструкция, как..." возможно в тексте (он дал инструкцию, как...), но в заголовке выглядит несолидно (как элемент беллетристики, напоминает "сказ о том, как..."). Вариант: **КАК СТРИЧЬ СОБАК**; подзаголовок в следующей строке: "*инструкция*" или "*описание процесса*". Второй ваш вариант изменений не требует.